# Link URL as a Primary Dimension in Landing Page Report

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I customized my Landing Page Report so that apart from Page Title, I can see the Link URL as well.

I went to the edit icon, customize the dimension, and added the link URL. But when I applied and saved my report it was showing only the complete/aggregated (total data). Why is this so? Does waiting for 24-48 hours for the report to populate make sense?